# How to aggregate the experience duration in pyspark of exploded rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have exploded the json data to structured format. Now I want to calculate the experience_expdurration on of the user of multiple rows? How can  we aggregate total experience duration from the multiple rows of same user? Any sugesstion will be help full

[image: +-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+ | fullName|Experience_datesEmployeed|Experience_expcompany|Experience_expdescription|Experience_expduraation|Experience_location| Experience_position| +-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+ |Jonathan Fong, CAIA| Aug 2010 – Dec 2010| Student Investmen...| Porfolio Manager ...| 5 mos| Sacramento, CA| Portfolio Manager| |Jonathan Fong, CAIA| Dec 2011 – May 2016| University of the...| Provided investme...| 4 yrs 6 mos| Sacramento, CA| Investment Analyst| |Jonathan Fong, CAIA| May 2016 – Present| CalPERS| | 4 yrs 4 mos| Sacramento, CA| Investment Officer| |Jonathan Fong, CAIA| Aug 2010 – Dec 2010| Boudames Investme...| Conducted researc...| 5 mos| Sacramento, CA|Investment Analys...| |Jonathan Fong, CAIA| May 2007 – Nov 2008| State Street Bank| Determined valuat...| 1 yr 7 mos| Sacramento, CA|Senior Fund Accou...| +-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+--------------------+]

**Data CSV file format**

```
fullName,Experience_datesEmployeed,Experience_expdescription,Experience_expduraation
Jonathan,Aug 2010 – Dec 2010,Porfolio Manager,5 mos
Jonathan,Dec 2011 – May 2016,Provided investor,4 yrs 6 mos
Jonathan,May 2016 – Present,Porfolio Manager,4 yrs 4 mos
Jonathan,Aug 2010 – Dec 2010,Porfolio Manager,5 mos
Jonathan,May 2007 – Nov 2008,Porfolio Manager,1 yr 7 mos
```

Comment: copy and paste, do not use the image, then we cannot reproduce.

Comment: and do group by

Comment: @Lamanus I have updated the question with data in CSV format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I am not good for the regular expression, so it looks not good, anyway working.

```
val regexp1 = "(\\d?)( yr | yrs )"
val regexp2 = "(\\d?)( mos| mo)"

df.withColumn("years",  regexp_extract($"Experience_expduraation", regexp1, 1).cast("int"))
  .withColumn("months", regexp_extract($"Experience_expduraation", regexp2, 1).cast("int"))
  .na.fill(0)
  .withColumn("totalMonths", $"years" * lit(12) + $"months")
  .groupBy("fullName")
  .agg(sum("totalMonths").as("totalMonths"))
  .show

+--------+-----------+
|fullName|totalMonths|
+--------+-----------+
|Jonathan|        135|
+--------+-----------+
```